# Текст между символов если имеет символ

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Есть разного вида текст:

```
((текст1)/(текст2)/(текст3))

(текст1) и (текст2)

Текст (один/два) тут еще текст(один/два)иещетекст
```

Задача выбрать текст между скобками если в тексте есть косая черта `/`

То есть, первая строка должна вернуть `((текст1)/(текст2)/(текст3))`, вторая ничего не вернет, третья `(один/два)` или `(один/два)` - не глобальный поиск.

Если использую:

`/\(([^\)|\(]*?)\)/i` - то первая вернет не всю себя а только первое вхождение `(текст1)`

`/\((.*\/+.*)\)/i` - последняя строка ведет себя не так как хочется, вернет - `один/два) тут еще текст(один/два`

Возможно что то посоветуете?

Comment: То есть необходима проверка парности скобок? Тогда регулярками не отделаетесь.

Comment: Парность скобок не параметр, т.к. есть и другие варианты где есть текст между первыми скобками в первом примере. У меня вопрос свелся сейчас только в том, как выбрать между скобок если внутри был символ `/`, что бы во втором исключить выборку и в третьем не выбирать текст который за скобками. Вторая регулярка так и делает, но спотыкается из-за жадности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно не регулярное выражение, а парсер:

```js
function spfun(text) {
  var result = []; // массив результата
  var flag = false; // флаг найденного слеша на первом уроне скобок
  var sum = 0; // количество открытых скобок
  var cur = ''; // текущая подстрока между открытыми скобками первого уровня, открывающаяся скобка захватывается, закрывающаяся подставляется при записи в массив результата
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    switch (text[i]) {
      case '(':
        sum++;
        break;
      case ')':
        sum--;
        if (sum < 0) {
          sum = 0;
        } else if (sum == 0) {
          if (flag) {
            result.push(cur + ')');
          }
          cur = '';
          flag = false;
        }
        break;
      case '/':
        if (sum == 1) {
          flag = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (sum > 0) {
      cur += text[i];
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(spfun('((текст1)/(текст2)/(текст3)) (текст1) и (текст2) Текст (один/два) тут еще текст(один/два)иещетекст (слеш на (втором/ уровне) скобок)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

вариант

```js
var str = "Текст (один/два) тут еще текст(один/два)иещетекст",
  reg = /\(\S+(?:\/)\S+\)/;
console.log(str.match(reg));
str = "(текст1) и (текст2)";
console.log(str.match(reg));
str = "((текст1)/(текст2)/(текст3))";
console.log(str.match(reg));
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, только не сработает на `Текст(один/два)т(один/два)и`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(text1|text2)(.*?)\1
```

Внутренний текст во второй группе.